# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hi i am try to call a stored procedure in a Entity select Query. but i got error.
first i check the procedure in out side.

```
  var img = dc.get_User_Image(1).FirstOrDefault();  
  var Task = from tbl_Task tsk in dc.tbl_Task
             join tmp in dc.tbl_TaskAssignment 
             on tsk.TaskID equals tmp.TaskID into jointable
             from tmp in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join ct in dc.tbl_User on tmp.AssignTo equals ct.UserID
             where tsk.IsDeleted == false && tsk.TaskID == IntTaskID && 
             tmp.IsDeleted == false
             select new
             {
                TaskID = tsk.TaskID,
                TaskDesc = tsk.Remarks,
                TaskTitle = tsk.TaskTitle,
                TaskEmpName = tmp.tbl_User.tbl_Contact.FirstName_EN,
                TaskEmpID = tmp.AssignTo,
                profileImage = "",
                Priority = tsk.Priority,
                TaskCompletedPercentage = tmp.CompletedPercentage

              };
```

no error. got the result. but change code to :

```
 var Task = from tbl_Task tsk in dc.tbl_Task
            join tmp in dc.tbl_TaskAssignment on tsk.TaskID equals tmp.TaskID into jointable
            from tmp in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join ct in dc.tbl_User on tmp.AssignTo equals ct.UserID
            where tsk.IsDeleted == false && tsk.TaskID == IntTaskID && 
            tmp.IsDeleted == false

            select new
            {
               TaskID = tsk.TaskID,
               TaskDesc = tsk.Remarks,
               TaskTitle = tsk.TaskTitle,
               TaskEmpName = tmp.tbl_User.tbl_Contact.FirstName_EN,
               TaskEmpID = tmp.AssignTo,
               profileImage = dc.get_User_Image(tmp.AssignTo).FirstOrDefault(),
               Priority = tsk.Priority,
               TaskCompletedPercentage = tmp.CompletedPercentage
           };
```

got a error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String]
>   get_User_Image(System.Nullable`1[System.Int64])' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

" dc.get_User_Image "  accept "user ID" (Int) and return image path (String).
in first code i am check the function, in seperate. it working fine.
in select Query iam call this-> 
"profileImage = dc.get_User_Image(tmp.AssignTo).FirstOrDefault()". it thrown error

i can't Understand why ?
plz help.

Comment: Whats different between your code samples? questions must **describe the specific problem**, where is the error?

Comment: It's because the query provider wasn't written in such a way as to be able to understand the use of that method in that context.  Why *should* the query provider understand that method?  What SQL should that be translated into?

Comment: Could you show the schema for dc or explain what get_User_Image is?

Comment: `dc.get_User_Image(tmp.AssignTo).FirstOrDefault()` What value it returns and what type `profileImage`  expects ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var Task = (from tbl_Task tsk in dc.tbl_Task
        join tmp in dc.tbl_TaskAssignment on tsk.TaskID equals tmp.TaskID into jointable
        from tmp in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join ct in dc.tbl_User on tmp.AssignTo equals ct.UserID
        where tsk.IsDeleted == false && tsk.TaskID == IntTaskID && 
        tmp.IsDeleted == false

        select new
        {
           TaskID = tsk.TaskID,
           TaskDesc = tsk.Remarks,
           TaskTitle = tsk.TaskTitle,
           TaskEmpName = tmp.tbl_User.tbl_Contact.FirstName_EN,
           TaskEmpID = tmp.AssignTo,

           Priority = tsk.Priority,
           TaskCompletedPercentage = tmp.CompletedPercentage
       }).AsEnumerable().select(row=> new {
task = row,
profileImage = dc.get_User_Image(tmp.AssignTo).FirstOrDefault()
```

})

Answer (score 2):

`dc.get_User_Image(tmp.AssignTo)` is, I presume,  an actual CLR method that wraps access to a stored procedure in your database; it's not an actual stored procedure itself.

Entity Framework cannot translate a call to an arbitrary method into SQL, hence the error message. You will need to materialize your query (e.g. `ToList()`) and *then* run your transformation function (`Select new {...}`) on it in order for that function to be usable.